# What is error in below code in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In inialize page I am fetching the id like below which is giving error as SelectAllCheckBoxForLocalCounterParty is undifined:

```
var abc = {LocalCounterpartyControl:<%=  IndividualBusinessInfoPanel.SelectAllCheckBoxForLocalCounterParty.ClientID %>};
    alert(a);
    $("[id^=" +abc.LocalCounterpartyControl + "]").bind("click", function () {alert('hi')});
```

but when same code if i used like this then it is working fine

```
$("[id^=<%= IndividualBusinessInfoPanel.SelectAllCheckBoxForLocalCounterParty.ClientID %>]").bind("click", function () {alert('hi')});
```

Please let me know what i have done mistake in first code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to insert a space between : and <%= ?

Comment: I dont understand what u trying to say. Please elaborate.

Comment: Change LocalCounterpartyControl:<%= to LocalCounterpartyControl: <%=

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `id` in single quotes after `id^=`:

```
 $("[id^='" +abc.LocalCounterpartyControl + "']").bind("click", function () {alert('hi')});
```

Comment: Still not working. Alert box is not promting. Thanks

Comment: have you tried suggestion by Jai and check in viewsource what is the value for LocalCounterpartyControl in abc variable.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in double quotes `""`:

```
var abc = {
   LocalCounterpartyControl: "<%= IndividualBusinessInfoPanel.SelectAllCheckBoxForLocalCounterParty.ClientID %>"
};
```

Its a javascript object and value part if that is not an integer has to be wrapped in `""` double quotes.

And yes you need to have a string represenation like this as bhushan also suggested:

```
$("[id^='" +abc.LocalCounterpartyControl + "']")
```

This helps you to not to worry about some special characters like `[], $ etc.` if they are comming dynamically.